# Mercurial/Redmine - 404 Error When Accessing Repository

Tags: mercurial, redmine

Hopefully this is a quick fix for those with experience!

I just finished up installing Mercurial and Redmine on my shared hostgator server to the tee from Redmine and Mercurial documentation, but have run in to a small problem. Mercurial works pefectly, I was able to create a repo, clone it, and sync to it without any issues, except when I add the repo to Redmine and go to the repository tab, I get a 404 error. I made sure to double check that I set the directory beginning from the root and it didn't work. I tried multiple different kinds of ways of writing out the directory but still No luck. I ended up opening my production.log, and this is the entry written every time I get the 404 error.

```
Processing RepositoriesController#show (for 74.56.***.*** at 2012-01-10 13:59:43) [GET]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"show", "id"=>"testhg1", "controller"=>"repositories"}
hg: error during getting info: hg exited with non-zero status: 255
hg: error during getting info: hg exited with non-zero status: 255
Rendering template within layouts/base
Rendering common/error (404)
Completed in 280ms (View: 12, DB: 2) | 404 Not Found [http://redmine.mydomain.org/projects/testhg1/repository]
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I recently set up Mercurial with Redmine and got a 404 error. I'm fairly sure that it was an incorrect password for Mercurial so you should try that.

Comment: OK, I know at least 3 people have had this error.  I guess I'm going to have to solve it myself.

Comment: @SteveKaye I use `hg serve` without any username and passport and get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

We ran into the same error on a Centos 6.3 server.
In our case, we were also getting the following error in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`:

```
abort: requirement 'dotencode' not supported!
```

We were creating our repositories using RhodeCode which was using a much newer version of mercurial (2.3.2) than the one that comes with CentOS 6.3 (1.4).  Updating the version of mercurial on the system using a pre-built RPM from repoforge solved the problem.  The extremely old version of mercurial available from yum on CentOS did not support the `dotencode` capability that the newer 2.3.2 Mercurial was using.

Answer (score 0):

Went into development mode to get some better logging:

```
Processing RepositoriesController#show (for ***.***.***.*** at 2012-03-15 22:54:47) [GET]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"show", "id"=>"go", "controller"=>"repositories"}
  Setting Columns (0.9ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `settings`

... more unimportant queries ...

  Repository::Mercurial Columns (0.7ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `repositories`
Shelling out: '/usr/bin/hg' '-R' '/var/lib/hg/godc' '--encoding' 'utf-8' '--config' 'extensions.redminehelper=/var/www/corp/redmine/lib/redmine/scm/adapters/mercurial/redminehelper.py' '--config' 'diff.git=false' 'rhsummary'
hg: error during getting info: hg exited with non-zero status: 255
Shelling out: '/usr/bin/hg' '-R' '/var/lib/hg/godc' '--encoding' 'utf-8' '--config' 'extensions.redminehelper=/var/www/corp/redmine/lib/redmine/scm/adapters/mercurial/redminehelper.py' '--config' 'diff.git=false' 'rhmanifest' '-r' 'tip' ''
Rendering template within layouts/base
Rendering common/error (404)
```

so the error seems to be with this command:

```
'/usr/bin/hg' '-R' '/var/lib/hg/godc' '--encoding' 'utf-8' '--config' 'extensions.redminehelper=/var/www/corp/redmine/lib/redmine/scm/adapters/mercurial/redminehelper.py' '--config' 'diff.git=false' 'rhsummary'
```

which works fine when I run is as root

```
root@redacted:/var/www/corp/redmine# '/usr/bin/hg' '-R' '/var/lib/hg/godc' '--encoding' 'utf-8' '--config' 'extensions.redminehelper=/var/www/corp/redmine/lib/redmine/scm/adapters/mercurial/redminehelper.py' '--config' 'diff.git=false' 'rhsummary'

... returns XML that S. O. doesn't want to show ...
(if you know how to fix this, please edit)
```

but my webserver runs as www-data which doesn't have access to the hg dir

```
root@redacted:/var/www/corp/redmine# sudo su - www-data
$ '/usr/bin/hg' '-R' '/var/lib/hg/godc' '--encoding' 'utf-8' '--config' 'extensions.redminehelper=/var/www/corp/redmine/lib/redmine/scm/adapters/mercurial/redminehelper.py' '--config' 'diff.git=false' 'rhsummary'
abort: repository /var/lib/hg/godc not found!
$ ls -l /var/lib/hg
ls: cannot open directory /var/lib/hg: Permission denied
$
```

give my www-data user access to the repo and the command now works:

```
$ groups
www-data hg
$ '/usr/bin/hg' '-R' '/var/lib/hg/godc' '--encoding' 'utf-8' '--config' 'extensions.redminehelper=/var/www/corp/redmine/lib/redmine/scm/adapters/mercurial/redminehelper.py' '--config' 'diff.git=false' 'rhsummary'

... returns XML that S. O. doesn't want to show ...








$
```

Tested it on redmine and still got the error but when I restarted apache everything was as it should be.

(I'm using phusion passenger.)

The upgrade turned out to be a red herring, the actual thing that caused this was the change from running with script/server as my user (which had repo access) to running as a properly installed phusion passenger production instance.

In your case, with your presumably $7/month hostgator shared server install, I'm sure you don't have access to modify permissions but you can at lest use the process I described to try and determine the problem.  I don't know much about hostgator's install but it seems likely that you might be having the same issue.